# Parsing data with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying parse data to variable. Data are represented as string in format like this :

```
code          time
0.00000       3.33333
1.11111       4.44444
2.22222       5.55555
```

I'm using match method to retrive all words and numbers in to array:

```
result = mystring.match(/(\w+)/g);
```

Words like code and time are match good but I have problem with numbers which are splitted to 2 numbers.

```
code
time
0
00000       
3
33333
1
11111       
4
44444
2
22222       
5
55555
```

What I would like to achieve is this :

```
code
time
0.00000       
3.33333
1.11111       
4.44444
2.22222       
5.55555
```

Comment: `\w` doesn’t include `.`. It looks like you actually just want non-whitespace, `\S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use split for this and split on all `whitespaces`.

```js
var match = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.split(/\s+/g); 

console.log(match);
```

```html
<pre>
code          time
0.00000       3.33333
1.11111       4.44444
2.22222       5.55555
</pre>
```

Reversed with match works too

```js
var match = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.match(/\S+/g); 

console.log(match);
```

```html
<pre>
code          time
0.00000       3.33333
1.11111       4.44444
2.22222       5.55555
</pre>
```